# How to exclude files from only one srcDir in a sourceSet?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have a java project with two resource directories, `res` and `raw`. I've set this up in my `build.gradle` like so:

```groovy
sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs = ['res', 'raw']
```

Both of these directories contain a subdirectory called `graphics`. The issue is I want to exclude the `graphics` directory from `raw`, but not from `res`.

I have tried:

```groovy
sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs = ['res', 'raw']
sourceSets.main.resources.exclude 'raw/**/graphics'
```

but this does not work, because the `exclude` pattern is relative to the `srcDirs`.

How do I set an `exclude` pattern only for the `raw` directory?

Comment: Not an answer, but... why not simply store everything that consitutes a resource under src/main/resources, and everything that doesn't elsewhere. It would make you own life easier, and make things less confusing (even if you end up with a solution).

Comment: @JBNizet that would be ideal but unfortunately this is an old project who's layout can't be changed for various reasons.

Comment: As an alternative, you could probably just configure the processResources task to copy everything except graphocs from the raw directory.

Comment: Or call the method srcDir() instead of setting the srcDirs, and modify the returned SourceDirectorySet

Answer (score 0):

The reason that didn't work is because the expression: `sourceSets.main.resources.exclude 'raw/**/graphics'`, creates a new live view of the files, where the excluded files do not exist.

Simply put, it does not affect `sourceSets.main.resources`.

To make it "permanent", you have to use the groovy DSL syntax:

```
sourceSets.main {
    resources {
        srcDirs 'res', 'raw'
        exclude 'raw/**/graphics'
    }
}
```